# Is it possible to adjust an array in PostgreSQL to fit with an IN operator?

Tags: postgresql

Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE something IN ('{"val1","val2"}'::text[]);
```

I tried it with array_to_string().

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE something IN (array_to_string('{"val1","val2"}'::text[]));
```

But I guess that makes it to this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE something IN ('val1,val2'); --one single string
```

I guess the single values must also be surrounded with apostrophes.

Is that possible somehow, or can it be solved in a completely different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ANY operator:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE something = ANY ('{"val1","val2"}'::text[]);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work: ERROR: syntax error at or near "ANY"

Comment: I missed the equal sign. Now it actually works. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [`ANY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.30.16):

```
SELECT * 
FROM example
WHERE something = ANY('{"val1","val2"}'::text[]);
```

But if you insist on using `IN`, you can achieve the same with [`UNNEST`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html):

```
SELECT * 
FROM example
WHERE something IN (SELECT UNNEST('{"val1","val2"}'::text[]));
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/jR3y7YOC))</sup>